# How can I have a view <th> tag render markup correctly?

Tags: 8, views

Objective : show a link on the column heading of the table so that the user can reach an explanation page on the content of the column.

I am having trouble figuring out how to add a link to a `<th>` tag in my View, simply.

So I need a field label to contain HTML.

For example if I enter `<a href="/node/1">My field label</a>` in Field configuration label input, the resulting table header is not a link and the markup is visible (plain text).

Table Format settings : no sticky headers and no sortable columns.

Any tip here?

**Views Field Configuration:**
[image]

**The result:**
[image]

Comment: You can use a twig template and insert the link via twig.

Comment: What are your Table Format settings? Drupal can use sticky headers for tables, and it can set the table header cells as sorting links for their columns, so overriding table header cells with links is a lot more nuanced than simply changing the field label. Can you use a different Formatter than Default to get the link you want? Have you tried Rewrite options?

Comment: @prkos question edited. Default Formatter and Rewrite options are only working with Field value and not Label, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, Formatter and Rewrite work on values, I must have been thought about the Style options, there is a separate Label option there. It does allow for the change in HTML element, but the anchor isn't on the list. The Label field is meant to be taking in only text, no HTML, so you might need to preprocess or twig that Label to allow HTML as input, then your link might work as you've written it. You'd still have to careful with setting table Format options (sorting etc).

Comment: I guess Patrick Kenny had the solution since the beginning then, as stated (and then erased later...). I suppose I need to create views-view-field--view-name--field-body.html.twig and write the appropriate output? Could anyone point me to the right direction with Twig syntax here?

Answer (score 0):

with Views UI, in the `HEADER`section, add a Global Text area with this Content in Text format = Full HTML:

```
<a href="/whatever/path/location" title="some text" class="form-submit">Ajouter</a>
```

and it gives something like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering but this not in the View header I need a link, this is in table header (th).

Comment: @Toki – Screenshots in your question may help clarifying this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe using `hook_views_pre_view`...

```
function hook_views_pre_view(ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args)
{
  switch ($view->id()) {
    case 'your_view_id':
      switch ($display_id) {
        case 'your_view_display_id':
          $fields = $view->display_handler->getOption('fields');
          foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == something) {
              $newLabel = 'whatever';
              $view->setHandlerOption($view->current_display, 'field', $key, 'label', $newLabel);
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
      }
      break;
    default:
  }
}
```

I use it only to change the label of some fields but you may try to handle your link this way.